# java stream find match or the last one?

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How to find the first match or the last element in a list using java stream?

Which means if no element matches the condition，then return the last element.

eg:

```
OptionalInt i = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,5)
                         .filter(x-> x == 7)
                         .findFirst();
System.out.print(i.getAsInt());
```

What should I do to make it return 5;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given the list

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

You could just do :

```
int value = list.stream().filter(x -> x == 2)
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(list.get(list.size() - 1));
```

Here if the filter evaluates to true the element is retrieved, else the last element in the last is returned.

If the list is *empty* you could return a default value, for example -1.

```
int value = list.stream().filter(x -> x == 2)
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(list.isEmpty() ? -1 : list.get(list.size() - 1));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `reduce()` function like that:

```
OptionalInt i = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
        .reduce((first, second) -> first == 7 ? first : second);
System.out.print(i.getAsInt());
```

Comment: That's brilliant. You might want to use the `reducing () ` collector though, which allows you to give an identity element, so you're able to handle empty and one element streams.

Comment: @daniu the only problem is that this is not short-circuiting, so if your first match happens to be on the first element, you would still have to traverse the entire stream's source, even if you know the result already.

Comment: @Eugene totally agree. Basically I would use LinkedHashSet to check element existence and return last element otherwise.

Comment: @Eugene good point, but is `reduce ()` short-circuiting?  Also, there actually is a`reduce () ` with identity element, but I was past editing by the time I had looked it up.

Comment: @daniu there is no special handling of single element streams required. Further, for an empty stream this simply returns an empty `Optional`, which allows to deal with the situation in whatever way you want, without the need to invent an identity element for the operation.

Comment: @daniu there is no such `reduce` that would be short-circuiting, in our code base at work, we throw an Exception without stack-trace to exit the reduce, but traversing the source in our case is a little more expensive, that is the reason we do it

Comment: `reduce` is not meant to perform searches, but associative operations instead, i.e. sum of elements. There are methods in `Stream` called `findAny` and `findFirst` to do this. Besides, if the stream was parallel, this wouldn't work, while `findFirst` would do the exact job, despite the characteristics of the stream. As others have stated, this doesn't short-circuit either...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner this function is associative, so it wouldn’t have any problems with parallel execution. So the only problem is that it is inefficient.

Comment: @Holger I stand corrected. The function is actually associative, so it is mathematically correct.

Answer (score 5):

Basically I would use one of the following two methods or deviations thereof:

Stream variant:

```
<T> T getFirstMatchOrLast(List<T> list, Predicate<T> filter, T defaultValue) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(filter)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(list.isEmpty() ? defaultValue : list.get(list.size() - 1));
}
```

non-stream variant:

```
<T> T getFirstMatchOrLast(Iterable<T> iterable, Predicate<T> filter, T defaultValue) {
    T relevant = defaultValue;
    for (T entry : iterable) {
        relevant = entry;
        if (filter.test(entry))
            break;
    }
    return relevant;
}
```

Or as also [Ilmari Karonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411022/ilmari-karonen) suggested in the comment with `Iterable<T>` you are then able to even call `stream::iterator` in case you really deal with a `Stream` instead of a `List`. Calling the shown methods would look as follows:

```
getFirstMatchOrLast(Arrays.asList(1, 20, 3), i -> i == 20, 1); // returns 20
getFirstMatchOrLast(Collections.emptyList(), i -> i == 3, 20); // returns 20
getFirstMatchOrLast(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 20), i -> i == 7, 30); // returns 20
// only non-stream variant: having a Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2, 20)
getFirstMatchOrLast(stream::iterator, i -> i == 7, 30); // returns 20
```

I wouldn't use `reduce` here because it sounds wrong to me in the sense, that it also goes through the whole entries even though the first entry could have matched already, i.e. it doesn't short-circuit anymore. Moreover for me it isn't as readable as `filter.findFirst.orElse`... (but that's probably just my opinion)

I probably would then even end up with something as follows:

```
<T> Optional<T> getFirstMatchOrLast(Iterable<T> iterable, Predicate<T> filter) {
    T relevant = null;
    for (T entry : iterable) {
        relevant = entry;
        if (filter.test(entry))
            break;
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(relevant);
}
// or transform the stream variant to somethinng like that... however I think that isn't as readable anymore...
```

so that calls would rather look like:

```
getFirstMatchOrLast(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5), i -> i == 7).orElseThrow(...)
getFirstMatchOrLast(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5), i -> i == 7).orElse(0);
getFirstMatchOrLast(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5), i -> i == 7).orElseGet(() -> /* complex formula */);
getFirstMatchOrLast(stream::iterator, i -> i == 5).ifPresent(...)
```

Comment: I like your "non-stream variant" (with or without Optional), but I'd suggest generalizing it to accept any `Iterable<T>` instead of just a `List<T>`. That way, if you do in fact _need_ to process a stream, [you can just pass `stream::iterator` to this method.](https://ideone.com/4McmOL)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to do this in one pipeline then you could do:

```
int startInc = 1;
int endEx = 5;
OptionalInt first = 
       IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(startInc, endEx)
                .filter(x -> x == 7), endEx > 1 ? IntStream.of(endEx) : IntStream.empty())
                .findFirst();
```

but you're probably better off collecting the generated numbers into a list then operate on it as follows:

```
// first collect the numbers into a list
List<Integer> result = IntStream.rangeClosed(startInc,endEx)
                                   .boxed()
                                   .collect(toList());
    // then operate on it 
int value = result.stream()
                  .filter(x -> x == 7)
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(result.get(result.size() - 1));
```

Alternatively, if you want to make the latter return an empty Optional in the case of the source being empty (if that's a possible scenario) instead of an exception then you could do:

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.rangeClosed(startInc,endEx)
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(toList());

Optional<Integer> first = 
         Stream.concat(result.stream().filter(x -> x == 7), result.isEmpty() ? 
                Stream.empty() : Stream.of(result.get(result.size() - 1)))
                .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you really want to use streams for that, a simple `for`-loop would be enough:

```
public static <T> T getFirstMatchingOrLast(List<? extends T> source, Predicate<? super T> predicate){
    // handle empty case
    if(source.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    for(T t : source){
        if(predicate.test(t)){
            return t;
        }
    }
    return source.get(source.size() -1);
}
```

Which then can be called like:

```
Integer match = getFirstMatchingOrLast(ints, i -> i == 7);
```